# Memory mapped database

Tags: database, windows, database-design

I have 8 terabytes of data composed of ~5000 arrays of small sized elements (under a hundred bytes per element). I need to load sections of these arrays (a few dozen megs at a time) into memory to use in an algorithm as quickly as possible. Are memory mapped files right for this use, and if not what else should I use?

Comment: Will access be primarily random or sequential?

Comment: sequential. Also if feasible I would like to query from multiple threads and also grow the arrays at their ends.

Comment: So you have no need for sophisticated DB features such as indexing and search keys, sorting, etc?  This is basically a sequential access flat file problem?  And I take it you can code pretty closely to the app's needs and don't need to produce a general-purpose API.

Comment: exactly - and this is guaranteed to be on a 64bit windows platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirements I would definitely go with memory mapped files.  It's almost exactly what they were made for.  And since memory mapped files consume few physical resources, your extremely large files will have little impact on the system as compared to other methods, especially since smaller views can be mapped into the address space just before performing I/O (eg, those arrays of elements).  The other big benefit is they give you the simplest working environment possible.  You can (mostly) just view your data as a large memory address space and let Windows worry about the I/O.  Obviously, you'll need to build in locking mechanisms to handle multiple threads, but I'm sure you know that.